# sfValidatorRegex not working

Tags: validation, forms, symfony1

I am trying validate a username field on a register form so that a username can only be made up of letters.  However, when I use the sfValidatorRegex(), it always returns invalid ("johnny" will return invalid, as does "JoHnNy").  Here's the code I'm using:

```
// From RegisterForm.class.php

$this->validatorSchema['username'] = new sfValidatorRegex(
  array(
    'pattern' => '[A-Za-z]',
  ),
  array(
    'invalid' => 'only lowercase letters',
  )
);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't understand whether you wanted lower or uppercase but try:

Only lowercase: `'/^[a-z]*$/'`

Lower or uppercase: `'/^[A-z]*$/i'`

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm.  I suspected that my syntax was off for the pattern.